# Turning motor on and off from webserver

Tags: python, pi-2, php, dc-motor

I have Apache server running on my pi. I send a httprequest from my Java app to the server to turn the motor on and off by executing a pyhton script. PHP code on the server:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["on"])){
 echo "turning on";
 exec("python /home/pi/motor/on.py /dev/null/ 2>/dev/null/ &")
}

if(isset($_POST["off"])){
 echo "turning off";
 exec("python /home/pi/motor/off.py")
}
?>
```

I think my problem is when turning the motor on, my application freezes as the exec call has not returned yet (because my python code is in a loop and can only exit when interrupt arrives). I want to be able to turn the motor on and off, but I can only turn it on.
Any solutions for this problem or another way of achieving what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
exec("python /home/pi/motor/on.py /dev/null/ 2>/dev/null/ &")
```

There's a > missing. To redirect the standard output, it must read

```
exec("python /home/pi/motor/on.py >/dev/null/ 2>/dev/null/ &")
```

If you don't redirect both the standard output and standard error channels, php's exec() waits for completion, regardless of an &.

Comment: hmm this worked anyway. Thnaks.

Comment: It's the same for you "off" script. You have to redirect standard output and standard error.

Answer (score 1):

If you migrate your web server from php to flask, you can give the motor command natively. Make routes as @app.route('/motor-on') and ('/motor-off'), with their respective python commands, then trigger the motor control with ajax request on button click (java script). **TIP:** Use gpiozero library, it is super easy and effective.

Comment: The thing is it has to be a Java app controlling the motor. Can flask work with java?

Comment: [speculative] yes i guess.

Comment: Assuming that you are using Java to read a web server response, then it is recommendable to simplify your setup to either Python or PHP. Partially, that is a matter of preference and skill. However, the Raspberry community is producing a lot of Python libraries which makes PHP a bit more difficult choice.

To state in another way: Java sees web pages as text, so as long as your server produces text in a way understood by your Java app, the technology behind the curtain does not matter.